# I designed a PCB in Altium, but the schematic has been deleted. How to design the schematic from the PCB?

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, altium

I designed a PCB in Altium Designer, but the schematic has been deleted. How to design the schematic from the PCB?

Comment: Altium retains quite a bit of history. If you actually designed the PCB yourself you may be able to retrieve it. Otherwise, I'm afraid it will be just like a reverse engineering job except you presumably know what you did before.

Comment: This is a good reminder to use version control (git, SVN, etc.) in hardware designs.

Answer (score 3):

Check if you have a netlist file (e.g., .dsn, .txt) that was generated when you initially designed the PCB. This file contains information about the connections between components. You can import this netlist into Altium to create a basic schematic structure.

Altium and other PCB design software might have reverse engineering tools or plugins that attempt to extract a schematic from the PCB layout. While these tools might not produce a perfect schematic, they can provide a starting point.

Quality of the reconstructed schematic might vary based on the complexity of the PCB